# How to solve error "E: Package 'snapd-xdg-open' has no installation candidate"

Tags: apt

hello i want to say that i am trying to install '**

- snapd-xdg-open

**' in my computer but it shows following error i searched a lot but not found please help me the code is :

```
sudo apt-get install snapd snapd-xdg-open
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package snapd-xdg-open is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  snapd

E: Package 'snapd-xdg-open' has no installation candidate
```

i have successfully install snapd but can't install snapd-xdg-open please help

Comment: You haven't told us what release you are on, but https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=snapd-xdg-open show's it's available for all supported releases, do you have 'universe' enabled?  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

Comment: Sorry but I did not get you

Comment: I don't know what OS & release you are using, if I knew that I'd do some check for you. Because of that my advice was generic via a packages.ubuntu.com page. That page shows 'universe' repository is where it's located, thus i asked if you have it enabled? providing link with details, however I don't know your OS & release so can't be more specific as my guess as to your OS & release may differ with what you're using and clear commands be incorrect/unhelpful (*yy.mm* releases have more commands available than say a *yy* release, I don't know your release.. etc).